# Click on button to display div which should be fixed when scrolling down. Div not showing properly though?

Tags: javascript, scroll, css-position, fixed

I have a fixed header which has a button (menu icon) on it. Whenever I scroll down the header will show (as it’s fixed). When I click on the menu button the menu is then also in a fixed position on the right hand side. When I scroll down both header and menu show which is fine. THE PROBLEM is when I initially scroll down half way down the page AND THEN click on the menu button the menu (div) is at the top-when I scroll a bit then it displays. There's a delay in this. Do you know how I can get the menu to display regardless of where I am on the page (in terms of y position)????

Top is set as 100px for the menu in a class (as the headers height is 100px-so i want the menu to show under it) BUT obviously if I’m already half way down the page the menu still takes into account the top: 100px however, I want it to change because I’ve scrolled down so the top position value would be different.

Any help??

Comment: Sorry for not being helpful here but I hope you realize this is like going to the auto repair shop describing your car problems while leaving your car at home.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a shot in the dark, I think your problem is **where** your fixed position checks are taking place - I.E, I'm guessing they're within the .scroll event of the window.

Before you scroll down, and you click on the menu button, it is set to display block in its initial position - which is correct, because you haven't scrolled down yet.

However, if you scroll down first, then display the menu - it's still going to display in it's initial position - because the *check* is in your .scroll event - which you haven't fired while the menu has been open.

Try applying the position check in the button logic too.